# React Native => Getting Screen Names for Navigation

Tags: react-native, npm, navigation, listdir

İf possible;

How to get list names of the files of a folder then use that names to create navigation links to pages using expo react native, My code as shown below, I want to add them like Auto Navigator Adder Object from here to pass props to HomeScreen to create navigation buttons.

And I know this question will be answered 8 months later, so thanks in advance. :)

App.js

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import ComponentsScreen from "./src/screens/ComponentsScreen";
import ListScreen from "./src/screens/ListScreen";
import ImageScreen from "./src/screens/ImageScreen";
import CounterScreen from "./src/screens/CounterScreen";
import ColorScreen from "./src/screens/ColorScreen";
import TextScreen from "./src/screens/TextScreen";
import BoxScreen from "./src/screens/BoxScreen";
import FlexScreen from "./src/screens/FlexScreen";


import listReactFiles from "list-react-files";
listReactFiles().then(files => console.log(files));


const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Components: ComponentsScreen,
    List: ListScreen,
    Image: ImageScreen,
    Counter: CounterScreen,
    Color: ColorScreen,
    Text: TextScreen,
    Box: BoxScreen,
    Flex: FlexScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: "App",
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rn-starter-update",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start -p 19000 -a",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "expo": "~49.0.10",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "list-files": "^1.1.4",
    "list-react-files": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried [list-react-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-react-files) and [list-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-files?activeTab=readme) packages => non stop loading screen awaits.. So I cant even console log the file names.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand well what you want to achieve but I far as know, you can't automatically generate your navigation stack in **React Navigation**.

Maybe you can try something with the new [Expo Router](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/introduction/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I am looking a script solution for this software.